# Unity - Object spins madly when rotating to the right - How to fix it

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to make my object (an aircraft in this case) turning. It turns smoothly when tilt on the left, but then it spins madly when it comes to the right. My method is simple: when the object tilts, the y rotation of the object will change correspondently to the z rotation of the camera (the tilting of the object follows the camera's z rotation). The object's y and the camera's z are reverse in sign. Could you show me some ways to fix this? Thank you very much! Sorry for my bad English.

Here is my code:

```
void Turn()
{
    float tilt = 0.05f;
    if(mainCam.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z<0)
    {
        tilt *= (-1);
    }

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(mainCam.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, transformY -= (Mathf.Round(mainCam.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z) * tilt), mainCam.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z);
    print(Mathf.Round(mainCam.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z) * 0.01f);
}
```

Comment: its because you dont rotate on a per-frame basis. have a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html especially https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html . do some tutorials btw.

Comment: if so, then it's supposed to happen to both left and right, yet it happens to the right only